I don't know how to save conversation history with ChatGPT
I'm creating a chatbot by using ChatGPT and Flask.
However, the way of using ChatGPT API can't continue conversation so that I'm finding the solution.
In addition, I don't accept the method which causes system clash using a lot of memory.
This is the code which I'm using to proceed conversation with ChatGPT through Flask server.
@app.route('/ask', methods=['POST'])
def handle_query():
    data = request.json
    prompt = data.get('prompt', '')
    
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are an assistant."},
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
        api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY
    )
    gpt_response = response.choices[0]['message']['content']
    
    return jsonify({"response": gpt_response})

